# How to extract data in Microsoft excel that satisfies certain criteria

Tags: excel-formula

The question I have is kind of confusing, so I am going to give a little background on the particular task I'm working on so you can have a better understanding. In one of the spreadsheets I am working on (Called the Fixture Mix Template), I have a list with a bunch of fixture components that are identified by their respective codes (the company calls them oracle codes), which are listed in Column G. Out of these components, some are categorized as "main components" and if they are a main components, they will have their oracle codes in Column E within their respective rows. For the components that aren't "main components" I just left their cells blank in this column. On a separte worksheet (Called the SUmmary Tab), I have a table that lists the main component codes with the costs that it takes to make and assmeble them. The question I was wondering is if anyone knows a particular formula I could use where if a component on the Fixture Mix Template tab is identified as a main component, then it would autopopulate the table on sheet 2 in the cells where someone would have to enter in the main component oracle code. I hope this makes sense!

I will also show you a picture to give a better understanding as well. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPaZg.jpg (this worksheet is called the Fixture Mix Template). My main question is if anyone knows a way where I could extract only the cells that have an oracle code in column E of that worksheet into column A of this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xAno.jpg (This is another tab in my workbook called the Summary tab)

IMAGES Posted

First Image:[image]
Second Image:[image]

Comment: Do you need it to be automatic? would a copy and paste work?

Answer (score 0):

I will edit my answer later and show how to apply it to your data later, but the following link will show you how to extract a distinct list of items in one column based on the critera in another column.

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/06/27/how-to-create-a-unique-distinct-list-where-other-columns-meet-two-criteria/

Hope this helps,